# Duplicate conditional statements in the factory

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

How to get rid of them? I'm wondering if there is a pattern or something that addresses this problem. Basically I need to instantiate a concrete child class based on the type property of another class, i.e. if type=1 then new A, else if type=2 then new B etc. I've ended up with this kind of a factory in the class with the type property:

```
/**
 * Get a ticket decorator based on the ticket type
 * @return ReferralService\TicketDecorator
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function getTicketDecorator(): ReferralService\TicketDecorator
{
    if (!$this->code) {
        throw new Exception("Couldn't create a ticket wrapper based on the type without a code");
    }

    /**
     * The debug service
     * @var Debug\Service $debugService
     */
    $debugService = app(Debug\Service::class);
    $debugService->setDebug(config('referral.debug'));

    switch ($this->code) {
        case self::TYPE_FEEDBACK:
            return new ReferralService\TicketDecorator\FeedbackTicketDecorator($debugService);
            break;
        case self::TYPE_BIRTHDAY:
            return new ReferralService\TicketDecorator\BirthdayTicketDecorator($debugService);
            break;
        case self::TYPE_NEW_PARTNER:
            return new ReferralService\TicketDecorator\PartnerTicketDecorator($debugService);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception(sprintf("Couldn't instantiate a ticket decorator based on the %s type", $this->code));

    }
}

/**
 * Instantiate a private page based on the ticket type
 * @param ReferralService\Service $service
 * @param Referrer $referrer
 * @param Ticket $ticket
 * @return ReferralService\Page\PrivatePage
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function getPrivatePage(ReferralService\Service $service, Referrer $referrer, Ticket $ticket): ReferralService\Page\PrivatePage
{
    if (!$this->code) {
        throw new Exception("Couldn't create a private page based on the type without a code");
    }

    switch ($this->code) {
        case self::TYPE_FEEDBACK:
            return new ReferralService\Page\PrivatePage\EmailReference($this->service, $referrer, $ticket);
            break;
        case self::TYPE_BIRTHDAY:
            return new ReferralService\Page\PrivatePage\Birthday($this->service, $referrer, $ticket);
            break;
        case self::TYPE_NEW_PARTNER:
            return new ReferralService\Page\PrivatePage\Partner($this->service, $referrer, $ticket);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception(sprintf("Could't find a page for the type", $this->code));
    }
}
```

Every method in the factory tests the type field, this looks clumsy for me. I thought to have a separate child class for every type and use factory methods without conditional statements, but I can't do so with Laravel models.

Comment: It's not pretty but there's nothing wrong with it. It's quite a readable, legit way to have a factory. I wouldn't worry about it too much

Comment: You can already remove all the useless `break;` (after the `return`s).

Comment: @Casimir right, I've just so got used to using the break statements all the time

Comment: @Andrew yep I'm going to leave it as is unless I have something more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: I actually don't since what you wrote is very functional and to the point. As I said, I'd go with it, it's legit.

Comment: @Andrew I wouldn't say that there is nothing wrong. It does violate the OCP at the very least. Why not simply replace conditionals with polymorphism? `$privatePage = ticketType.createPrivatePage()`. Looks simple enough. The type becomes the factory.

Comment: @plalx the factory methods are placed in a Laravel Eloquent model. If I used polymorphism, I would have 1 abstract model and multiple child models per type. The problem is that Eloquent won't cope with that, it can't instantiate a child model based on the type. Anyway I end up with a factory either a) a factory method in the abstract model, it instantiates a concrete ticketType model b) New abstract factory. The ticketType model has a factory method that produces a concrete factory that in turn produces all these pages/decorators using polymorphism. Factory that produces factory, haha.

Comment: @plalx do you think the two ways from my last comment make sense? At least they allow to use the conditional statement once, not multiple times.

Comment: @Sergey It's still better to have the factory for concrete types because all other type-based decisions will not require conditional statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very common refactoring pattern to [replace conditionals by polymorphism](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).

You could just implement a factory to create specialized `TicketType`s and implement factory methods on the ticket types to create concrete `TicketDecorator` and `PrivatePage`.

However, just keep in mind that this does introduce coupling between `TicketType` and the concrete classes it creates. If it preferable to avoid such coupling then stick to your initial design.

Comment: why anyone would like to avoid such coupling?

Comment: @Sergey It mainly depends on the level of abstractions and the coupling between modules. E.g. if you had `ProductType` that lives in a `Product` module but the type is used to choose the shipping strategy in the `Shipping` module then you may want to avoid coupling `Product` to `Shipping` since it's `Shipping` that should proably be coupled to `Product`. Not the best example, but hopefully it will make sense to you.

Comment: yes it does, thank you. I'll probably do a factory method inside of the TicketType class that picks out one of the concrete classes that override an abstract factory that produces concrete pages and decorators using polymorphism. It a bit differs from your answer, but still pretty much the same.

Comment: @Sergey What would be the advantage of the abstract factory here?

Comment: well the original conditional statements are placed in an Eloquent ORM model. If I did multiple models per table, Eloquent wouldn't be able to manage them properly, for example when converting query results into a collection. The abstract factory seems to be more simple and fast solution in my case, I don't have to touch and think about Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my solution. I've decoupled the `TicketType` (the class from the original post with the conditional statements) from everything so that it's not aware of the pages/decorators.

At the same time I've created the concrete ticket classes: `BirthdayTicket`, `PartnerTicket`.

I've placed a factory method into the `Ticket` class that produces a concrete instance of the ticket class based on the ticket's type - `BirthdayTicket`, `PartnerTicket` etc. The concrete ticket classes produce the things I need (pages, decorators) using polymorphism as suggested by @plalx above.